# Is there a faster way to separate the minimum and maximum of two arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, minimum

```
In [3]: f1 = rand(100000)
In [5]: f2 = rand(100000)

# Obvious method:
In [12]: timeit fmin = np.amin((f1, f2), axis=0); fmax = np.amax((f1, f2), axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.2 ms per loop

In [13]: timeit fmin, fmax = np.sort((f1, f2), axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.8 ms per loop

In [14]: timeit fmin = np.where(f2 < f1, f2, f1); fmax = np.where(f2 < f1, f1, f2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.73 ms per loop


In [36]: f1 = rand(1000,100,100)

In [37]: f2 = rand(1000,100,100)

In [39]: timeit fmin = np.amin((f1, f2), axis=0); fmax = np.amax((f1, f2), axis=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.13 s per loop

In [40]: timeit fmin, fmax = np.sort((f1, f2), axis=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.3 s per loop

In [41]: timeit fmin = np.where(f2 < f1, f2, f1); fmax = np.where(f2 < f1, f1, f2)
1 loops, best of 3: 617 ms per loop
```

Like, maybe there's a way to do both `where` commands in one step with 2 returns?

Why isn't `amin` implemented the same way as `where`, if it's so much faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use numpy's built in element-wise `maximum` and `minimum` - they are faster than `where`.
The notes in the [numpy docs for maximum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) confirm this:

> Equivalent to np.where(x1 > x2, x1, x2), but faster and does proper broadcasting.

The line you would want for your first test would be something like:

```
fmin = np.minimum(f1, f2); fmax = np.maximum(f1, f2)
```

My own results show this to be quite a bit faster. Note that `minimum` and `maximum` will work on any n-dimensional array as long as the two arguments are the same shape.

```
Using amax                    3.506
Using sort                    1.830
Using where                   0.635
Using numpy maximum, minimum  0.178
```

Comment: Wait, what!?  I thought those were synonyms for `amin` and `amax` for some reason. The docs don't even link to each other.  Sigh.  That is indeed much faster.